# ImageTk.PhotoImage doesn't show up on OSX, but does on Windows

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

This script of mine shows the logo.png image when run in Windows but does not show the image (even though it generates a large enough space for it) when the script is run in Mac OS X terminal.

I have tried to create a separate variable as described by solutions to this problem but cannot get the image to load.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class TestPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text, height, width, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, borderwidth=20, **kwargs)
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        #Test Frame
        self.testFrame = tk.Frame(self)

        self.logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.png'))
        global logo
        logo = self.logo
        self.logolabel=tk.Label(self.testFrame, image=self.logo)
        self.logolabel.pack()


        self.testFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='both', expand = 'yes')

        self.update()
        self.onlift()

    def onlift(self):
        root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(self.width, self.height))
        self.lift()
        root.update()


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global p1
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = TestPage(self, 'blank', height=root.winfo_screenheight(), width=root.winfo_screenwidth())
        p1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        root.update()


global p1
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('LTEST01 V2.0 GUI')
app = App(root)
root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would really help if you removed all code unrelated to this problem. For example, your page really only needs just the label that has the image. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could it be a image file path problem? The argument to `Image.open()` isn't necessarily just a file name, it's a file _path_, and that might be different on the two platforms.

Comment: Also, as @Bryan, suggests, please [edit] your question so the code in it is the minimum required to reproduce the problem. See [**_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BryanOakley Code is now minimized

Comment: @martineau I have tried different ways of writing the path to the file. The image is in the same folder the script runs in.

Comment: @aroushan: It's very good to hear you ruled-out it being a image file path problem (as well as minimized the sample code in your question). Before you even did that I was able to verify that the code works with Windows 7. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to a system running OSX, so can't see if I can reproduce the issue. But now it should be relatively easy for others to this. It's possible this is a `pillow` bug. I encountered a few of them in the past. Good news is that if you report it, they'll take a look and try to fix it.

Comment: @martineau so strange that converting the file to jpeg worked! So i think you are right and it is a pillow issue. I will report it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Converting to RGB solved the problem.

so make your code like this:

```
self.logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.png').convert('RGB'))
```

Basically the transparent images with Alpha channel seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the combination of "transparency mask", MACOS and pyinstaller does not work. RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true-color with transparency mask) does not work as well. Sadly, only converting to RGB solved the problem.